# Trigger will not run (added more information)

Tags: triggers, marklogic, marklogic-8

I have been tinkering with this trigger for hours now, think I pinpointed the issue now.

I have set up an example trigger like in [ML8 documentation](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/triggers#id_66092).

Now I have modified it to a more real-world action.

The issue seems to be that I use a library module that hold my own functions in a lib.xqy. I have tested the lib itself in Query Console, all functions run fine.

The alert action itself also runs fine in QC.

The simpleTrigger works ok.

The more complex one runs IF I REMOVE the function that uses my own lib.

Seems that the trigger is run by a user or from a place where it cannot find my module (which is in the modules db). I have set the trigger-db to point to the content-db.

The triggers look at a directory for new documents (document create).

If I want to use my own lib function the Error thrown is:

```
[1.0-ml] XDMP-MODNOTFOUND: (err:XQST0059) xdmp:eval("xquery version 
&quot;1.0-ml&quot;;&#10;&#10;let $uri := '/marklo...", (), 
<options xmlns="xdmp:eval"><database>12436607035003930594</database>
   <modules>32519102440328...</options>) 
-- Module /lib/sccss-lib.xqy not found
```

The module is in the modules-db...

Another thing that bothers me is the example in ML doc does a

```
xdmp:document-insert("/modules/log.xqy", 
  text{ "
xquery version '1.0-ml';
..."
}, xdmp:permission('app-user', 'execute'))
```

What does the permission app-user do in this case?

Anyway main question: Why does the trigger not run if I use a custom module in the trigger action?

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31991607/calling-xquery-libraries-with-dependencies-from-rest-endpoints-in-marklogic-8) and think it is related but I do not understand the answer there...

EDIT start, more information on the trigger create statement:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace trgr="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/triggers" 
   at "/MarkLogic/triggers.xqy";

trgr:create-trigger("sensorTrigger", "Simple trigger for connection systems sensor, the action checks how long this device is around the sensor", 
  trgr:trigger-data-event(
      trgr:directory-scope("/marklogic.solutions.obi/source/", "1"),
      trgr:document-content("create"),
      trgr:post-commit()),
  trgr:trigger-module(xdmp:database("cluey-app-content"), "/triggers/", "check-time-at-sensor.xqy"),
  fn:true(), xdmp:default-permissions() )
```

Also indeed the trigger is created from the QC, so indeed as admin(I yet have to figure out how to do that adding code to app-specific.rb). And also the trigger action is loaded from the QC with a doc insert statement equivalent as the trigger example in the docs.

For completeness I added this to app-specific.rb per suggestion by Geert

```
  alias_method :original_deploy_modules, :deploy_modules
  def deploy_modules()
    original_deploy_modules

    # and apply correct permissions
    r = execute_query %Q{
      xquery version "1.0-ml";

      for $uri in cts:uris()
      return (
        $uri,
        xdmp:document-set-permissions($uri, (
          xdmp:permission("#{@properties["ml.app-name"]}-role", "read"),
          xdmp:permission("#{@properties["ml.app-name"]}-role", "execute")
        ))
      )
    },
    { :db_name => @properties["ml.modules-db"] }
  end
```

For testing I also loaded it as part of the content (using ./ml local deploy content to load it, as said before the action is there it will run so there seems no issue with the permission of the action doc itself. What I do not understand is that as soon as I try to use my own module in the action it fails to find the module or(see comment David) does not have the right permission on the module. So the trigger action will fail to run ... The module is loaded with roxy under /src/lib/lib.xqy

### SECOND EDIT

I added all trigger stuf to include in roxy by adding the following to app_specific.rb:

```
  # HK voor gebruik modules die geen REST permissies hebben in een rest extension
  alias_method :original_deploy_modules, :deploy_modules
  def deploy_modules()
    original_deploy_modules

    # Create triggers
    r = execute_query(%Q{
        xquery version "1.0-ml";

        import module namespace trgr="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/triggers" 
           at "/MarkLogic/triggers.xqy";

        xdmp:log("Installing triggers.."),

        try {
          trgr:remove-trigger("sensorTrigger")
        } catch ($ignore) {
        };


        xquery version "1.0-ml";

        import module namespace trgr="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/triggers" 
           at "/MarkLogic/triggers.xqy";

        trgr:create-trigger("sensorTrigger", "Trigger to check duration at sensor", 
          trgr:trigger-data-event(
            trgr:directory-scope("/marklogic.solutions.obi/source/", "1"),
            trgr:document-content("create"),
            trgr:post-commit()
          ),
          trgr:trigger-module(xdmp:modules-database(), "/", "/triggers/check-time-at-sensor.xqy"),
          fn:true(),
          xdmp:default-permissions(),
          fn:false()
        )
      },
      ######## THIRD EDIT ###############
      #{ :app_name => @properties["ml.app-name"] }
      { :db_name => @properties["ml.modules-db"] }
    )

    # and apply correct permissions
    r = execute_query %Q{
      xquery version "1.0-ml";

      for $uri in cts:uris()
      return (
        $uri,
        xdmp:document-set-permissions($uri, (
          xdmp:permission("#{@properties["ml.app-name"]}-role", "read"),
          xdmp:permission("#{@properties["ml.app-name"]}-role", "execute")
        ))
      )
    },
    { :db_name => @properties["ml.modules-db"] }
  end
```

As you can seee the rootpath is now "/" in line

```
trgr:trigger-module(xdmp:modules-database(), "/", "/triggers/check-time-at-sensor.xqy")
```

I also added permissions by hand but still as soon as I add the line pointing to sccs-lib.xqy my trigger fails...

Comment: Did you also tried this? trgr:trigger-module(xdmp:database([modules database for the clue-app]), "/", "/triggers/check-time-at-sensor.xqy"),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a number of criteria that need to be met for a trigger to work properly. David already mentioned part of them. Let me try to complete the list:

- You need to have a database that contains the trigger definition. That is the database against which the `trgr:create-trigger` was executed. Typically `Triggers` or some `app-triggers`.
- That trigger database needs to be assigned as triggers-database to the content database (not the other way around!).
- You point to a trigger module that contains the code that will get executed as soon as a trigger event occurs. The `trgr:trigger-module` explicitly points to the uri of the module, and the database in which it is contained.
- Any libraries used by that trigger module, need to be in the same database as the trigger module. Typically both trigger module, and related libraries are stored within `Modules` or some `app-modules`.

With regard to permissions, the following applies:

- First of all, you need privileges to insert the document (uri, and collection).
- Then, to be able to execute the trigger, the user that does the insert needs to have a role (directly, inherited, or via amps) that has read and execute permission on the trigger modules, as well on all related libraries.
- Then that same user needs to have privileges to do whatever the trigger modules needs to do.

Looking at your create-triggers statement, I notice that the trigger module is pointing to the app-content database. That means it will be looking for libraries in the app-content database as well. I would recommend putting trigger module, and libraries in the app-modules database.

Also, regarding `app-user` execute permission: that is just a convention. The `nobody` user has the `app-user` role. That is typically used to allow the `nobody` user to run rewriter code.

HTH!

Comment: Completely forgot: `trgr:trigger-module` takes a modules-root value as second parameter, but keep in mind that will also be applied to any dependencies. It is usually more practical to stick with modules root `/`, and specify full uri path for the module to execute! This is also very likely the root cause here.

Comment: see second edit I added all trigger create stuff to app_specific now but the issue remains...

Comment: In the end the `modules-root` was indeed the main issue.

Comment: so finally after moving all trigger creates into app_specific and pointing to the modules database a clean deploy did it! I also made sure de triggerdatabase was set to the app-mocules-db by adding a line in build.properties...

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide a bit more information - like perhaps the entire trigger create statement?

For creating the trigger, keep in mind:

1. the trigger database that you insert the trigger into has to be the one defined in the content database you refer to in the trigger and
2. `trgr:trigger-module` allows you to define the module database and the module to run.  With this defined properly, then I cannot see how `/lib/sccss-lib.xqy` is not found - unless it is a permissions item...

Now on to the other item in your question: you test stuff in query console. That has the roles of that user - often run by people as admin...  MarkLogic gives a 'not found' message also if a document is there - and you simply do not have access to it.  So, it is possible that there is a problem with permissions for the documents in your modules database.

Comment: Ad 1. The trigger-db point to the app-content-db, keep in mind that thetrigger and the simple example trigger both run, only when adding the module with custom app functions it fails... Ad 2. I am confused now. The trigger-module is in my case pointing to the place where I put the trigger action... which is the app-content-db ... let me check now ...

Comment: okto test i moved the trigger to the modules db and pointed the trigger-db to the modules db so both the action and the lib now are in the same database, still no luck,same error. So permission issue? I dont get it as from the QC I am admin that should be enough permissions no? I cannot find any information when to run a trigger under what permissions other then app-user exec permission for the trigger action.